# Is StartUML 2 compatible with its previous version?

Tags: uml, visio, staruml

Previously I used for my work StarUml on Windows, all the data is saved with .uml extension.
Now we move to iOS and I was pretty happy with the announcement of the new StarUML 2 for Mac. Although with this program all the data is saved with .umlj extension.

Does it mean that both version are incompatible or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are not compatible. I had the same problem.

I exported all my StarUML projects to XMI files and then I imported them all in [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com/staruml). GenMyModel automatically detected the XMI format (UML 1.3) and it updated my class diagrams to UML2. Once imported, I could reuse my diagrams online and export them as images and XMI (UML2 files). That's the best bridge I could find out.